# Скольжение по кнопкам

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton, touch-event

Есть несколько кнопок. Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь, коснувшись одной кнопки, мог, не отрывая палец, переместить его на другую кнопку. Событие нажатия должно срабатывать только у той кнопки, на которой остановился пользователь.
Хотелось бы сохранить функционал UIButton, чтобы при наведении на кнопку у неё менялся цвет привязанный к состоянию (для подсветки выбранной кнопки).

Можно сделать это обычными UIView и UIPanGestureRecognizer, определять, куда указывает палец, и менять цвета.

Возможно, есть более правильный подход, чтобы сделать это с помощью UIButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, у меня получилось что-то в коде ниже, но кнопки придется самому обрабатывать, отключил их интерактивность, чтоб не перехватывали главное событие тача, и вот что вышло:

```
#import <Masonry/View+MASAdditions.h>
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
@end

@implementation TestViewController
{

    UIButton *buttonBlue;
    UIButton *buttonRed;
    UIButton *buttonGreen;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Configure Buttons
    buttonRed = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonRed setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonRed setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonRed setTitle:@"Red Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonRed setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonRed];

    buttonBlue = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonBlue setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonBlue setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonBlue setTitle:@"Blue Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonBlue setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonBlue];

    buttonGreen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonGreen setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonGreen setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonGreen setTitle:@"Green Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonGreen setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonGreen];

    UIView *superview = self.view;

    //ConstraintViews
    [buttonRed mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(superview);
        make.left.equalTo(superview);
    }];

    [buttonBlue mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(superview);
        make.right.equalTo(buttonGreen.mas_left);
        make.left.equalTo(buttonRed.mas_right);
        make.width.equalTo(buttonRed);
    }];

    [buttonGreen mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(superview);
        make.right.equalTo(superview);
        make.width.equalTo(buttonRed);
    }];

//    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGesture:)]];
//    [buttonRed addTarget:self action:@selector(redButtonTarget:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}

- (void)redButtonTarget:(id)redButtonTarget
{
    NSLog(@"%d", buttonRed.state);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [buttonRed setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonRed forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
    [buttonBlue setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonBlue forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
    [buttonGreen setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonGreen forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    [buttonRed setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonRed forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
    [buttonBlue setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonBlue forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
    [buttonGreen setHighlighted:[self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonGreen forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject]];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [buttonRed setHighlighted:NO];
    [buttonBlue setHighlighted:NO];
    [buttonGreen setHighlighted:NO];
    if ([self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonRed forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject])
    {
        //Call eventTarget
    }

    if ([self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonBlue forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject])
    {
        //Call eventTarget
    }

    if ([self p_isTranslationOnButton:buttonGreen forRecognize:touches.allObjects.firstObject])
    {
        //Call eventTarget
    }
}

- (BOOL)p_isTranslationOnButton:(UIButton *)button forRecognize:(UITouch *)recognize
{
    BOOL yes = (CGRectContainsPoint(button.frame, [recognize locationInView:self.view]));
    return yes;
}

@end
```

Залил тестовый проджект. Тока он подсозависимый. [Здесь](http://cl.ly/1M0l2w470A2V).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте стандартные события  `UIControlEvents: .TouchDown, .TouchUp, .TouchUpInside, .DragEnter, .DradExit, .DragInside, .DragOutside`, чтобы подсвечивать кнопки.

**Обновление**

Это обычные экшены у кнопки, такие как обработчик нажатия, просто добавляем необходимые экшны через `[button addTarget:self selector:@selector(didDragInside:) event: UIControlEventDragInside];` для нужных кнопок и получаем вызовы `- (void)didDragInside:(UIButton *)sender { /* обрабатываем "палец над кнопкой" */ }` и далее для всех нужных событий. Кнопка передается как параметр. `UIControlEventDragOutside` сработает, когда палец больше не над кнопкой и т.д. `touchesBegan` - норм вариант, даже не знаю, какой проще. Я бы если и делал не через `UIControlEvents`, то использовал бы `UIPanGesture`.

Comment: А можно подробнее? Как с помощью этих событий оперировать состоянием кнопок?
В данный момент реализовал, весь нужный мне функционал, с помощью UIView и перегрузкой методов touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded у UIViewController'а.

Comment: @Zatoichy, Это обычные экшены у кнопки, такие как обработчик нажатия, просто добавляем необходимые экшны через [button addTarget:self selector:@selector(didDragInside:) event: UIControlEventDragInside]; для нужных кнопок и получаем вызовы - (void)didDragInside:(UIButton *)sender { /* обрабатываем "палец над кнопкой" */ } и далее для всех нужных событий. Кнопка передается как параметр. UIControlEventDragOutside сработает когда палец больше не над кнопкой и тд. touchesBegan - норм вариант, даже не знаю, какой проще. Я бы если и делал не через UIControlEvents, то использовал бы UIPanGesture.